# Measure memory usage of ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory, instruments

As part of a research I'm working on, I would like to have a simple graph of the memory used by an iOS application (graph and the actual values in .csv format(or something alike)). I've been fooling around with all the different instruments tools but none of them seems to do the job. None of the tools (allocations, application monitor,...) is able to give me a simple graph of the total real resident memory of the application.

Is this even possible in Xcode? Are there any alternatives?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the source code from your app, Xcode will show you a 'simple graph'. When your app is running on a device or in the simulator choose the Debug Navigator `View > Navigators > Show Debug Navigator` then click on the small 'Memory' graph.

[image: Debug Navigator, Memory Profile in Xcode 7.1]

But when considering the memory usage of an app this is not the whole story. I think you are having trouble finding a 'simple graph' for memory usage because measuring memory usage of an App is not simple. There is the heap, the VM system, system frameworks which maybe shared between apps, all kinds of complexities.

Apple discuss the issues with analysing the memory usage of an app in [Session 410 from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-410/)